# Problem with custom processing button to generate NoteIDs

Tags: acumatica

Creating a new dummy maintenance screen to enable universal search on item cross references and gotten as far as creating the new DAC and BLC, even adding the Processing buttons to the screen, but when clicking the either processing button nothing happens (currently have it throwing a PXException). Ultimately I need to use the "Process All" (labeled "Create NoteIDs") button to fill in the NoteID field so I can actually work on the universal search part.

This is my graph. The INItemXRef is actually a new custom DAC with a NoteID field attached (no other changes, created directly from the database). Ultimately I need to update the code below to fill in random values to empty NoteIDs, so if there is any advice on the next step that would also be appreciated after solving the immediate problem:

```
public class INItemXRefGraph : PXGraph<INItemXRefGraph>
  {
    public PXSelect<INItemXRef> INItemXRef;
    public PXSave<INItemXRef> Save;
    public PXFilter<INItemXRef> MasterView;

    [PXFilterable]
    public PXProcessing<INItemXRef, Where<INItemXRef.noteID, IsNull>> INDocumentList;

    public INItemXRefGraph()
    {
        INDocumentList.SetProcessDelegate(ReleaseDoc);
        INDocumentList.SetProcessAllCaption("Create NoteIDs");
    }

    public static void ReleaseDoc(System.Collections.Generic.List<INItemXRef> list)
    {
        throw new PXException("Hello World");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public class INItemXRefGraph : PXGraph<INItemXRefGraph>
  {
    public PXSelect<INItemXRef> INItemXRef;
    public PXSave<INItemXRef> Save;
    public PXFilter<INItemXRef> MasterView;

    [PXFilterable]
    public PXProcessing<INItemXRef, Where<INItemXRef.noteID, IsNull>> INDocumentList;

    public INItemXRefGraph()
    {
        INDocumentList.SetProcessDelegate(
            delegate(System.Collections.Generic.List<INItemXRef> list)
            {
                System.Collections.Generic.List<INItemXRef> newlist = new System.Collections.Generic.List<INItemXRef>(list.Count);
                foreach (INItemXRef doc in list)
                {
                    newlist.Add(doc);
                }
                ReleaseDoc(newlist);
            }
        );
        INDocumentList.SetProcessAllCaption("Create NoteIDs");
    }

    public static void ReleaseDoc(System.Collections.Generic.List<INItemXRef> list)
    {
        throw new PXException("Hello World");
    }
```